# xlrd lookup Excel values in other Excel file

Tags: python, excel

I am playing around with xlrd and I am having some difficulties. The main idea of what I am trying to do is to open an Excel file, read the first column contents into an array and use that array to search in another Excel file. When the value is found it should return the contents of three cells from the second Excel file. my code:

```
import xlrd
import os.path
from docx import Document

document = Document()

registry = xlrd.open_workbook('/root/Desktop/registry.xlsx')
findings = xlrd.open_workbook('/root/Desktop/findings.xlsx')

findings_sheet = findings.sheet_by_index(0)
registry_sheet = registry.sheet_by_index(0)

num_rows = findings.nrows - 1
curr_row = 0

findings_array = []

while curr_row < num_rows:
   row = findings.row(curr_row)
   findings_array += row
   curr_row += 1


for finding in findings_array:
   for r in range(first_sheet.nrows):
       cell_col1=first_sheet.cell(rowx=r,colx=0).value
       if cell_col1 == finding:

           print first_sheet.cell(r,3)
           print first_sheet.cell(r,4)
           print first_sheet.cell(r,5)
else:
    print "Finding not found"
```

Currently it doesn't work. If i replace `if cell_col1 == finding:` into `if cell_col1 == "ABC":` then the condition works but it prints out the cells 5 times which is the number of findings in my array.

I know that I have issues in my code but I am not a programmer and I am kinda stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run your code and rewrite it in more pythonic-style:

```
import xlrd
import os.path

registry_doc = xlrd.open_workbook('/tmp/s.xlsx')
findings_doc = xlrd.open_workbook('/tmp/f.xlsx')

findings_sheet = findings_doc.sheet_by_index(0)
registry_sheet = registry_doc.sheet_by_index(0)

findings = {findings_sheet.cell_value(i, 0) for i in range(0, findings_sheet.nrows)}

for r in range(0, registry_sheet.nrows):
   cell_col1=registry_sheet.cell_value(rowx=r,colx=0)
   if cell_col1 in findings:
       print registry_sheet.cell_value(r,2)
       print registry_sheet.cell_value(r,3)
       print registry_sheet.cell_value(r,4)
```

It must work

Mistake was in `if cell_col1 == finding:`. 
You are comparing `str` and `list of cell`.

Comment: I would change the type of `findings_array` into a `set` and change the name to `findings` (even for a list `array` isn't a good name suffix).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **read the first column contents into an array**, this line:

```
findings_array += row
```

should be:

```
findings_array += row[0]
```